# How render 2 components in v-for list, with v-if condition?

Tags: vue.js

I wanna render 2 child components(A and B), in condition with v-for. First, wrapp 2 components with v-for, then A is allowed to render always, and B is only rendered in v-if is true.

like this:
AABAAAABAA

But, when I did, the components are like this:
AABBAAAAAA

I tried to provide B components with 'key' of v-for as props, but never solved.

```
<template lang="pug">
.wrapper(v-for="(item, index) in list") :key="index")
  Acomponent(someProps="someProps")
  Bcomponent(v-if="index === 1")
```

Comment: You cannot use `v-for` in a `v-for` attribute value (unless I'm misunderstanding how pug woks)

Comment: thanks for confirming. You mean `cannnot user v-if in a v-for` ?

Comment: No. Your template appears to have `v-for="(v-for="(item, index) in list")` which really doesn't make sense

Comment: @Phil
oh.. sorry, it's my mistake. Correctly,  `v-for="(item, index) in list` .

Comment: What you now have in your question should only render `B` once when `index` is `1`, eg `ABAAAA...`. Is that not happening?